# My Android App Takes Too Long To Search For Location But Doesn't Display It In The End

Tags: java, android, google-maps, userlocation

I was learning to develop an Android app with the GoogleMaps class. Now, in order for it function, I require the location data of the user. Now, it's all good up to this point. But whenever I install the app on my phone, the notification bar for the app shows that the app is looking for a user's location, but it takes too long to do this. In the end, however, it doesn't display it either.

Could anyone help me with this? I don't understand why this happens. I have also provided all the permissions in the manifest file as well.

For more clarity, here's the code:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            }

        }

    }
```

Apart from this, there's also another bit of code, that I have used for a final confirmation from the users whether they are sure about providing/not providing their location information:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }

        else {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit - Here's the complete body of code:

```
package com.example.userlocation;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Location" + location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);

        else {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your full code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: Sure. I've uploaded it.

Comment: Thank you. I've just tested your code and the toast displays my gps coordinates without problem and without much delay at all. What do you see instead? No toast at all? Do you have a good connection and valid API key?